# TeamCity Build Parameters: Reuse a checkbox with multiple values?

Tags: msbuild, preprocessor, teamcity

For my team city configuration, I have a build parameter with a potential preprocessor macro definition. It's a checkbox with this value: `/p:DefineConstants=IncludeFleetSimulation` . It has that value so that I can easily add that into my MSBuild parameters, obviously. However, I also want to change the output filename. I don't want `/p:...` in the filename. Instead, I want "IFS". Is there some way to insert something conditionally with the TeamCity parameter parsing? I'm picturing something like this: `%IFS% != "" ? "_IFS" : ""%` . How do I achieve that in TeamCity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a Nant script step to make this happen:

```
    <project name="RenameFilesBasedOnParamters" default="Rename">
     <target name="Rename">
     <property name="IncludeFleetSimulation" value="%IncludeFleetSimulation%" />
     <property name="currentDirectory" value="%system.teamcity.build.workingDir%" />
      <if test="${IncludeFleetSimulation != ''}">
       <foreach item="File" property="file">
        <in>
         <items basedir="${currentDirectory}">
          <include name="*%build.number%_%build.vcs.number%*" />
         </items>
        </in>
        <do>
         <move file="${file}"
               tofile="${currentDirectory + '\' + 
               path::get-file-name-without-extension(file) + 
               '_FS' + path::get-extension(file)}" />  
        </do>
       </foreach>  
      </if>
    ...
```